# NHibernate Queries with Values Produced by Business Logic

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I have an NH query which returns a Product with a BasePrice. Depending on various other factors, such as Manufacturer price markup, I use a PricingService on the C# side of things to produce a "final" price.

The issue is that I now need to query against this final value - i.e., I need to run a query that selects Products within a particular "final" price range, but because that value only exists on the C# side, I can't do an NH query against it.

I'm thinking that my approach to this is all wrong, but I really didn't want to put the logic of the final price calculation in a SQL function or something like that, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you persist the final price along with product? Why is it volatile andmust by calculatedon demand?

Comment: Well the final price depends on things that can be edited on the fly by site admins, such as a Manufacturer discount or a site-wide discount, all of which interact. Technically you are correct that changing one of these values could trigger an update across the database, but particularly with a site-wide discount, you'd be updating many records and having to do calculations regarding the interactions between discounts as you went.

Your suggestion could be a practical alternative, I admit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do your calculations in HQL or Linq (with the new provider in 3.x; the 2.x one is a little limited).

Comment: ??Can you show some examples of that? Are you saying you can use C# methods inside your HQL queries?

Comment: No, you can't use C# methods. But you *can* do projections and calculations that include other entities, inject the calculation parameters, etc.